# jQuery - hide if previous element has a particular class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to hide all class="csc-content" where previous sibling is a h4 class="faq".

UPDATE
Error: I think this is wrong... the previous sibling is not h4. But I hope you get the point that all "answer" shall be hidden if the "question" has the class "faq"
/UPDATE

This is the html:

```
<div id="centerCol-1">
  <div id="c65" class="csc-default normal">
    <div class="csc-header csc-header-n1"><h4 class="faq">FAQ question1</h4></div>
    <div class="csc-content active"><p class="bodytext">Answer1</p></div>
  </div>
  <div id="c67" class="csc-default normal">
    <div class="csc-header csc-header-n2"><h4 class="faq">FAQ question2</h4></div>
    <div class="csc-content active"><p class="bodytext">Answer2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div id="c68" class="csc-default normal">
    <div class="csc-header csc-header-n3"><h4>not FAQ</h4></div>
    <div class="csc-content active"><p class="bodytext">Not an answer, just normal content</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery should be something like:

```
// find all outer divs with class csc-default in the div centerCol-1
// test if they contain a header div with an h4 class faq
// go to next element and hide it. Error... this should be parents next element?
$("#centerCol-1 .csc-default").find("h4").is(".faq").next(".csc-content").hide();
```

BR. Anders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [adjacent](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) selector along with the [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$('#centerCol-1 .csc-default .csc-header:has(.faq)+.csc-content').hide();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/iyabi3/edit)

Comment: Wow! what an unbelivable fast answer! Great answer but I asked the wrong question and edited it while you answered.

Answer (score 3):

Hang on, you only want to hide the answer div for each FAQ question? So if the `h4` has the class `.faq`, the div immediately after the parent div gets hidden:

```
$("#centerCol-1 h4.faq").parent().next("div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#centerCol-1 .csc-content").filter(function() {
  return $(this).prev().find(".faq").length > 0;
}).hide();
```